# Why does input[type=color] interfere with the position of text on the same line?

Tags: html, css

Here is an example, this demo shows that text line is at wrong position(it is moved down by a few pixels).

If I remove the `type="color"` or add `.main{display: flex}`, the text's position would be ok.

I'm just curious, **why does this happen**? Perhaps this involves a problem with the **block layout** rules.

demo: https://codepen.io/ahuigo/pen/yLQjxew?editors=1010

```html
<div class="main">
  <b style="border: 1px solid;">text line</b>
  <input type="color" value="#0000ff">
</div>

<style>
.main{
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input{
  height: 22px;
}

input[type="color"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by wrong position. Where do you want it to be? Currently it appears to align with the characters’ baseline.

Comment: Ah, I’ve just seen your comment on removing type color and I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `padding: 0` on the color input, not the fact that it's a color input. You can fix it by making `main` a flex container, or using one of the other methods on [How to center in CSS](http://howtocenterincss.com/).

Also, `// foo` isn't a comment in CSS, you have to use `/* foo */`.

Comment: What do you mean by **not the fact that it's a color input**?
Why this will interfere with  the position of text line?

Yeah, flex is ok.

Comment: At least in Firefox, removing the zero padding on the color input fixes the alignment of the text element — the fact that it's a color input doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: I don't think so. This text's position will be ok if I remove the input's `type="color"` .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly but do you search for this solution?

```css
.line {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

input {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <b>text line</b>
  <input type="color">
</div>
```

make a parent div to put both in a `flexbox`. With `gap` you can set the spacing between the text and the input, would be cleaner than using margin-left or something like that...

Btw to get the input `border-radius` working you need to set `overflow: hidden`.

Hope it helps! :)

And yes, `// foo` isn't a comment in CSS, you have to use `/* foo */`. (Credits Zac Anger)

Comment: I have re-edited the question. My question is about the rules of block itself.(not flex)